# Configure PosgreSQL pool with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, environment-variables

I am trying to include environment variables to my pool object (starting by the database port). My file is like this:

```js
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' });

console.log(process.env.DATABASE_PORT)

const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    password: '123456',
    database: 'db',
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT
});

export = pool;
```

And I'm getting "Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'."

I've tried to substitute with

```js
port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT | 5432
```

and

```js
port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT | 5432)
```

but none of these are working.

I thought about using "!", but it does not seems to be a good practice (and also didn't work :b).

Any ideas on what i could do to solve this?

Comment: The default operator is `||`. You're using the bitwise or operator `|` which is incorrect.

Comment: `port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT | 5432)` As commented above, use `||` rather than `|`. Aside from that, don't try to convert 5432 to a number when it's already a number. `port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT) || 5432`

Comment: Thank you both, it's working :)

Answer (score 1):

solution will be like that

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config({ path: '.env' });

const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.PGUSER,
    host: process.env.PGHOST,
    database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
    password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT || '5432'),
});

export default pool;
```